# Selecting Random rows from a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a product table from which I have to select 5 random products. I tried getting rows by following query:-

```
        select prod.prod_id, prod.prod_id, prod.prod_subcateg_id
          , prod.prod_name , prod.prod_desc         
        from product prod
        where prod.prod_subcateg_id = 4 AND prod.prod_datetill is null
        order by random() limit 5;
```

Although I am getting random rows but there are instances when duplicate rows are being returned. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This query cannot return the same row more than once. Please provide sample data, current and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: It does in some iterations. Will share the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exclude duplicate rows you can use SELECT DISTINCT ON (prod.prod_id).
You can do a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (prod.prod_id) prod.prod_id,
                                        prod.prod_subcateg_id,
                                        prod.prod_name,
                                        prod.prod_desc
      FROM product prod
      WHERE prod.prod_subcateg_id = 4
        AND prod.prod_datetill is null) AS product
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: On using `DISTINCT` following error is thrown -  `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`